# Offset in Double Column References Section

Tags: bibliographies, vertical-alignment, multicol

I am using the following code to print double-column bibliography. However, there is an offset as shown in the figure below. How can I fix the code such that the left column goes up and starts properly like the right column?

[image]

Here is the working but minimal example of the code:

PREAMBLE:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dissertation}[2013/07/08 v1.0 TU Delft dissertation class]

\newif\if@nativefonts
\DeclareOption{nativefonts}{\@nativefontstrue}
\newif\if@print
\DeclareOption{print}{\@printtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt]{book}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
%% English is the default language, but Dutch is used for some sections.
\RequirePackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[nooneline,footnotesize]{caption}
\RequirePackage{chapterbib}
\RequirePackage{etaremune}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{gensymb}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xkeyval,float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{setspace}
\ifxetex
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{geometry}
    %%\RequirePackage[xetex]{graphicx}
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{hyperref}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \RequirePackage{xltxtra}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\else
    \ifpdf
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{geometry}
       %% \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
    \else
        \RequirePackage[dvips]{geometry}
        %%\RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage[hypertex]{hyperref}
    \fi
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{metalogo}
\RequirePackage[sectionbib,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}


%% If the document is not compiled with XeLaTeX, we need to use the native
%% fonts.
\ifxetex\else
    \@nativefontstrue
\fi

\if@nativefonts
    %% The native font is Utopia Regular with Fourier math. We use Latin Modern
    %% as a fallback, since Utopia lacks support for sans-serif and monospace.
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage{lmodern}
    \RequirePackage{fourier}
    %% The style for titles is small caps.
    \def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
    \def\titleshape{\scshape}
    \def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \if@print
        \def\headerstyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \else
        \def\headerstyle{\titlefont\titleshape}
    \fi
\else
    %% The TU Delft house style fonts are Bookman Old Style (serif) for titles
    %% and Tahoma (sans-serif) for text. Apart from these, we use Courier New
    %% for monospace and Cambria for math.
    \RequirePackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[
        Path = fonts/,
        Extension = .ttf,
        BoldFont = *-Bold,
        ItalicFont = *-Italic,
        BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
    ]{BookmanOldStyle}
    \setsansfont[
        Path = fonts/,
        Extension = .ttf,
        BoldFont = *-Bold,
        ItalicFont = *,
        ItalicFeatures = FakeSlant,
        BoldItalicFont = *-Bold,
        BoldItalicFeatures = FakeSlant
    ]{Tahoma}
    \setmonofont[
        Path = fonts/,
        Extension = .ttf,
        UprightFont = *MT,
        BoldFont = *-BoldMT,
        ItalicFont = *-ItalicMT,
        BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalicMT
    ]{CourierNewPS}
    \setmathfont[
        Path = fonts/,
        Extension = .ttf
    ]{CambriaMath}
    %% The default style for text is Tahoma (sans-serif).
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
    %% The default style for titles is Bookman Old Style (serif).
    \def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
    \def\titleshape{}
    \if@print
        \def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \else
        \def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape}
    \fi
    \def\headerstyle{\titlestyle}
\fi

%% Define the TU Delft house style colors.
\definecolor{tudelft-cyan}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-black}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}
\definecolor{tudelft-white}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-sea-green}{cmyk}{0.54,0,0.32,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-green}{cmyk}{1,0.15,0.4,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-dark-blue}{cmyk}{1,0.66,0,0.4}
\definecolor{tudelft-purple}{cmyk}{0.98,1,0,0.35}
\definecolor{tudelft-turquoise}{cmyk}{0.82,0,0.21,0.08}
\definecolor{tudelft-sky-blue}{cmyk}{0.45,0,0.06,0.06}
\definecolor{tudelft-lavendel}{cmyk}{0.45,0.2,0,0.07}
\definecolor{tudelft-orange}{cmyk}{0.02,0.56,0.84,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-warm-purple}{cmyk}{0.58,1,0,0.02}
\definecolor{tudelft-fuchsia}{cmyk}{0.19,1,0,0.19}
\definecolor{tudelft-bright-green}{cmyk}{0.36,0,1,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-yellow}{cmyk}{0.02,0,0.54,0}

%% Use TU Delft cyan as the color for titles, unless the 'print' option is
%% specified, in which case we use anthracite, a dark gray, which is also used
%% for the thumb indices.
\definecolor{anthracite}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.8}
\if@print
    \colorlet{title}{anthracite}
\else
    \colorlet{title}{tudelft-cyan}
    %\colorlet{title}{tudelft-cyan}
\fi
\colorlet{thumb}{anthracite}

%% Set the paper size to 17 by 24 cm, approximately halfway between A4 and A5.
\if@print
    %% In print mode we add a 3 mm bleed on the outside of the page.
    \geometry{
        papersize = {173mm,246mm},
        layoutsize = {167mm,240mm},
        layoutoffset = {3mm,3mm},
        bindingoffset = -3mm
    }
\else
    \geometry{papersize={170mm,240mm}}
\fi
%% We decrease the margins slightly from the default (scale = 0.7).
\geometry{hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8}

%% Redefine the title command to accept an optional subtitle.
\renewcommand*\title[2][]{%
    \def\@subtitle{#1}%
    \def\@title{#2}%
    %% Add the title to the PDF meta data.
    \hypersetup{pdftitle=#2}%
}
%% Redefine the author command to accept a first and last name, and to add the
%% full name to the PDF meta data.
\renewcommand*\author[2]{%
    \def\@firstname{#1}%
    \def\@lastname{#2}%
    \hypersetup{pdfauthor=#1\ #2}%
}

%% Remove the header and page number on empty pages.
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage%
    \if@twoside%
        \ifodd\c@page%
        \else%
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \vspace*{\fill}%
            \newpage%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}

\if@print%
    \newcommand*\cropmarks{%
        \ifodd\c@page%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \draw ($(current page.north east)+(0mm,-3mm)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-2mm,-3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.north east)+(-3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-3mm,-2mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south east)+(0mm,3mm)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+(-2mm,3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south east)+(-3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+(-3mm,2mm)$);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        \else%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \draw ($(current page.north west)+(0mm,-3mm)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(2mm,-3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.north west)+(3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(3mm,-2mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south west)+(0mm,3mm)$) -- ($(current page.south west)+(2mm,3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south west)+(3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.south west)+(3mm,2mm)$);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        \fi%
    }
\else
    \newcommand*\cropmarks{}
\fi%

%%% Thumb indices consist of white text on a rectangular colored background. The
%%% font-size is 75% of the size of thumb height.
\newif\ifthumb
\newlength\thumbheight
\setlength\thumbheight{24pt}
\newlength\thumbedge
\setlength\thumbedge{4pt}
\newlength\thumbhspace
\setlength\thumbhspace{36pt}
\newlength\thumbvspace
\setlength\thumbvspace{2\thumbheight}

\newlength\thumbwidth
\setlength\thumbwidth{36pt}
\newlength\thumbspacing
\setlength\thumbspacing{2\thumbheight}

%% We need the TikZ library calc to calculate the coordinates of the thumb
%% indices.
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%% The lthumb command prints the current chapter number in a thumb index on the
%% left (even) page.
\newcommand*\lthumb{%
    \ifthumb%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \coordinate (top margin) at (0pt,1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep);
            \coordinate (left margin) at (1in+\evensidemargin,0pt);
            %% Calculate the corners of the thumb index based on the current
            %% chapter number.
            \coordinate (top left) at ($(current page.north west)-(top margin)-(0pt,\value{chapter}\thumbvspace-\thumbvspace)$);
            \coordinate (bottom right) at ($(top left)+(left margin)-(\thumbhspace,\thumbheight)$);
            %% Shift the left edge to prevent the rounded corner from showing.
            \coordinate (top left) at ($(top left)-(\thumbedge,0pt)$);
            %% Draw the thumb index.
            \fill[fill=thumb,rounded corners=\thumbedge](top left) rectangle (bottom right);
            %% Print the chapter number at the center right in the thumb index.
            \coordinate (center right) at ($(bottom right)+(0pt,0.5\thumbheight)$);
            \node at (center right)[anchor=east,inner sep=2\thumbedge]{
                \titlefont\bfseries\color{tudelft-white}
                \fontsize{0.75\thumbheight}{0.75\thumbheight}\selectfont
                \thechapter
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi%
}

%% rthumb draws a thumb index on the right (odd) page.
\newcommand*\rthumb{%
    \ifthumb%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \coordinate (top margin) at (0pt,1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep);
            \coordinate (right margin) at (1in+\evensidemargin,0pt);
            %% Calculate the corners of the thumb index based on the current
            %% chapter number.
            \coordinate (top right) at ($(current page.north east)-(top margin)-(0pt,\value{chapter}\thumbvspace-\thumbvspace)$);
            \coordinate (bottom left) at ($(top right)-(right margin)-(-\thumbhspace,\thumbheight)$);
            %% Shift the left right to prevent the rounded corner from showing.
            \coordinate (top right) at ($(top right)+(\thumbedge,0pt)$);
            %% Draw the thumb index.
            \fill[fill=thumb,rounded corners=\thumbedge](top right) rectangle (bottom left);
            %% Print the chapter number at the center right in the thumb index.
            \coordinate (center left) at ($(bottom left)+(0pt,0.5\thumbheight)$);
            \node at (center left)[anchor=west,inner sep=2\thumbedge]{
                \titlefont\bfseries\color{tudelft-white}
                \fontsize{0.75\thumbheight}{0.75\thumbheight}\selectfont
                \thechapter
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi%
}

%% Page style for empty pages.
\fancypagestyle{empty}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{0pt}
    \fancyhead{\cropmarks}
}

%% Page style for title pages.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{0pt}
    \fancyhead{\cropmarks}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\titlefont\thepage}
}

%% Fancy style for the main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    %% Page numbers on the top left and top right.
    \fancyhead[LE]{\cropmarks\lthumb\titlefont\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\cropmarks\rthumb\titlefont\thepage}
    %% Chapter name on the left (even) page.
    %%\fancyhead[RE]{\changefont\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}    %%KA
    %\fancyhead[RE]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %% KA
    %% Section name on the right (odd) page.
    %\fancyhead[LO]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}} %% KA
}

%% The mainmatter style is default for normal pages.
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

%% Print the current chapter and section at the top of the page in cyan.
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \color{title}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{title}#1}}

%% The setheader command can be used to print the title of unnumbered chapters
%% in the page header.
\newcommand*\setheader[1]{\markboth{\color{title}#1}{\color{title}#1}}

%% Change the font size of fancy headers for chapters and section titles
\newcommand{\changefont}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}

%% Change the headrule command (from fancyhdr.sty) to draw the line below the
%% header in the title color.
\renewcommand*\headrule{%
    \if@fancyplain%
        \let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth%
    \fi%
    {\color{title}\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}%
    \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}

%% Draw the line above a footnote in the title color as well.
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{%
    \vspace*{-3pt}%
    {\color{title}\hrule width 0.5\textwidth height 0.4pt}%
    \vspace*{2.6pt}%
}

%% A part title starts with a huge (96pt) bold black number, flushed to the
%% right, followed by the part name on the next line in the title color.
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\flushright\titlestyle}
    {\fontsize{96pt}{96pt}\selectfont\bfseries\thepart}
    {0pt}
    {\Huge\color{title}}
%% Separate the title from the text by two empty lines.
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}
%% In the table of contents, the part name is preceded by an empty line, printed
%% in bold, and not followed by a line of dots.
\dottedcontents{part}[0em]{\vspace{\baselineskip}\titlefont\bfseries}{1.5em}{0pc}

%% Chapter titles have the same layout as parts.
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\flushright\titlestyle}
    {\fontsize{96pt}{96pt}\selectfont\bfseries\thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\Huge\color{title}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}
%% In the table of contents, a chapter is similar to a part, except that it is
%% preceded by half an empty line.
\dottedcontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\titlefont\bfseries}{1.5em}{0pc}

%% Section titles start with the number in bold, followed by the name printed
%% in the title color.
\titleformat{\section}
    {\Large\headerstyle}
    {\bfseries\thesection.\ }
    {0pt}
    {\color{title}}
%% Sections are preceded by an empty line.
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
%% In the table of contents, section names are followed by a line of dots 8pt
%% apart.
\dottedcontents{section}[3.8em]{\titlefont}{2.3em}{8pt}

%% Subsection titles have the same layout as section titles, except in a smaller
%% font.
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\large\headerstyle}
    {\bfseries\thesubsection.\ }
    {0pt}
    {\color{title}}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[7em]{\titlefont}{3.2em}{8pt}

%% Subsubsections have the same font and color as sections and subsections, but
%% are not preceded by a number.
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\headerstyle}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\color{title}}
%% Subsubsections are preceded by an empty line and do not appear in the table
%% of contents.
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\bigskipamount}{0pt}

%% Color the bullets of the itemize environment and make the symbol of the third
%% level a diamond instead of an asterisk.
\renewcommand*\labelitemi{\color{title}\textbullet}
\renewcommand*\labelitemii{\color{title}--}
\renewcommand*\labelitemiii{\color{title}$\diamond$}
\renewcommand*\labelitemiv{\color{title}\textperiodcentered}

%% The dedication is vertically centered on a separate page and flushed to the
%% right.
\newcommand\dedication[1]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{flushright}%
        #1%
    \end{flushright}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \cleardoublepage%
}

%% Define an unnumbered footnote command.
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}

%% The authors environment is used to display the authors of a chapter on the
%% title page. This is only necessary if multiple people contributed
%% significantly to the chapter.
\newcommand*\authors[1]{%
    \begin{center}%
        {\Large\bfseries #1}%
    \end{center}%
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}%
}

%% The epigraph environment can be used to to add a quote to the title page of
%% a chapter.
\newcommand\epigraph[3][2\baselineskip]{%
    \begin{flushright}%
        {\rmfamily\itshape #2}%
        \vskip 0.5\baselineskip%
        #3%
    \end{flushright}%
    \vspace{#1}%
}

%% The abstract environment is used for the abstract of a chapter.
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \list{}{\leftmargin\rightmargin}%
    \item%
    \relax%
    \rmfamily\itshape%
}{%
    \endlist%
}

%% Define a drop command which can be used to generate drop caps at the
%% beginning of a section.
\renewcommand*\LettrineTextFont{\titleshape}
\newcommand*\dropcap[2]{
    \lettrine[lines=2,findent=0.2em,nindent=0pt]{\color{title} #1}{#2}%
}



%% Create an unnumbered reference section.
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\bibname{\color{title}References}}
\newcommand*\references[1]{%
    %\section*{References}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{ \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{0.0mm} }
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \raggedcolumns
    \small
    \bibliographystyle{dissertation}%
    \bibliography{#1}%
    \end{multicols}
}

%\renewcommand{\refname}{ \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-1.1mm} }
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{paper_ref}


%% Hyperlinks are cyan, except in print mode, when they are all black.
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor = title,
    linkcolor = title,
    urlcolor = title
}

% Added setting 
%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}%

% Change the margin temporarily 
%\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
%\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

% Caption next to the figure
%\newlength{\myimagewidth}
%\newlength{\mycaptionwidth}
%\setlength{\mycaptionwidth}{\textwidth-\myimagewidth-10pt}
%
%\newcommand{\setmyimagewidth}[1]{\setlength{\myimagewidth}{#1}
%\setlength{\mycaptionwidth}{\textwidth-\myimagewidth-10pt}}


% Footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


% Caption next to the figure code-2
\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{iac}{left}[0pt]{}% \cmdKV@iac@left
\define@cmdkey{iac}{right}[0pt]{}% \cmdKV@iac@right
\define@cmdkey{iac}{figcapsep}[\tabcolsep]{}% \cmdKV@iac@figcapsep
\define@cmdkey{iac}{figwidth}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@figwidth
\define@cmdkey{iac}{capwidth}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@capwidth
\define@cmdkey{iac}{figlabel}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@figlabel
\define@cmdkey{iac}{captiontoc}[\relax]{}% \cmdKV@iac@captiontoc

\newcommand{\imageandcaption}[3][]{%
  \setkeys{iac}{
    left,right,figcapsep,figwidth,capwidth,figlabel,captiontoc,% Set default keys
    #1% Set updated keys
  }%
  \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@figwidth\relax% No figure width supplied
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@capwidth\relax% No caption width supplied
      \def\cmdKV@iac@figwidth{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\cmdKV@iac@left-\cmdKV@iac@right-\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep}%
      \def\cmdKV@iac@capwidth{\cmdKV@iac@figwidth}%
    \else% Caption width provided
      \def\cmdKV@iac@figwidth{\dimexpr\linewidth-\cmdKV@iac@left-\cmdKV@iac@right-\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep-\cmdKV@iac@capwidth}%
    \fi
  \else% Figure width supplied
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@capwidth\relax% No caption width supplied
      \def\cmdKV@iac@capwidth{\dimexpr\linewidth-\cmdKV@iac@left-\cmdKV@iac@right-\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep-\cmdKV@iac@figwidth}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \hspace*{\cmdKV@iac@left}% Indent from left margin
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=\cmdKV@iac@figwidth]{#2}% Insert image
  \hspace*{\cmdKV@iac@figcapsep}% Space between image and caption
  \begin{minipage}{\cmdKV@iac@capwidth}
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@captiontoc\relax
      \caption{#3}% \caption without ToC entry
    \else
      \caption[\cmdKV@iac@captiontoc]{#3}% \caption with ToC entry
    \fi
    \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@iac@figlabel\relax\else
      \label{\cmdKV@iac@figlabel}%
    \fi
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace*{\cmdKV@iac@right}% Space on right of construction
}
\makeatother
```

MAIN CLASS:

```
\documentclass{dissertation}

\begin{document}

%% Turn on thumb indices.
\thumbtrue

\include{chapter-6/chapter-6}

%% Turn off thumb indices for unnumbered chapters.
\thumbfalse

\end{document}

-- CHAPTER (there double column bibliography is used in here)

    \chapter[Introduction]{Introduction}


\section{Introduction}
XYZ.\cite{Pavkovich1986, Parikh1979, Owen1990} KLM.\cite{Zhou2006, Stepanova2010, Dai2011a, Dai2011, Manfrinato2014, Chang1975, Rishton1987}

\section*{References}
\references{ref6}


\end{document}
```

Hope you dont need the .bib file

Comment: Did you try issuing the instruction `\raggedcolumns` after loading the `multicol` package?

Comment: @Mico I have tried \raggedcolumns right after the \begin{multicols}{2}, but it did not work. Problem, I am hiding the title instead of removing it actually.

Comment: Then, by all means, don’t just post a code snippet but a full minimum working example ( MWE) that reproduces the issue you wish to fix. Incidentally, I have no idea what “hiding the title instead of removing it” may mean — or what the connection of this expression to the issue at hand may be. Sorry.

Comment: @Mico I have added a working code example (.bib is still missing)